# When & why I need to use web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

When & why I need to use  web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true, and why it is false by default:

```
 web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
 //Update Item
 web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
```

Comment: In a few rare scenarios, blindly setting it to false after doing the updates may caues issues, with other out-of-the-box code or with other custom code. It is a safer habit to save the original value Before changing it, then changing it back to the original value when done.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For reasons of security, by default, Microsoft SharePoint Foundation does not allow you to make posts from a Web application to modify the contents of the database unless you include security validation on the page making the request.  You can update data for a single site or for a site collection by adding a page directive and a FormDigest control to the page that makes the request.

To GET the content from the content DB, we need to set the AllowUnsafeUpdates = true. 
To POST the content to the content DB, not require to set the AllowUnsafeUpdates = true. why means because of "FormDigest" control placed in every master page.

[When/where/why use "AllowUnsafeUpdates" in SharePoint?](http://sharepointquicksolutions.blogspot.com/2012/03/whenwherewhy-use-allowunsafeupdates-in.html)

[Why do I need to use SPWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates?](http://gavinb.net/2014/05/21/why-do-i-need-to-use-spweb-allowunsafeupdates/)

[What You Need To Know About AllowUnsafeUpdates (Part 1)](https://hristopavlov.wordpress.com/2008/05/16/what-you-need-to-know-about-allowunsafeupdates/)

Comment: This answer is correct from a technical perspective. However, there are no valid scenarios in which custom code should use AllowUnsafe.  If you are writing custom code, you should use the FormDigest or first make a call to _api/contextinfo.

Comment: I think there's still an error. You need unsafe updates allowed to *make updates during the processing of a GET request,* not to GET data from database.

Comment: unfortunately i can't understand the answer, it seem correct, but is there an simple way to describe it. why we don't need something like this with ASP.net Applications?

Comment: @jobin because SharePoint.

Comment: @jobin Say you have a list and you want to update something to the SharePoint data [content DB], then you need to set AllowUnsafeUpdates = true for the web and after you have done you need to set it back to false.

Comment: yes, but why? with asp.net, I can insert row to database without things such this.

Answer (score 4):

**WHY** --> to prevent your code from cross site scripting.

If you are updating content DB using a POST request then you should use **SPUtility.ValidateFormDigest()**  to validate the current request and after that you will not have to worry about **AllowUnsafeUpdates**, because its default value will be “true” after the form digest is validated.
The Microsoft idea behind introducing the **AllowUnsafeUpdates** property is to protect you from cross-site scripting attacks.

If you are using GET request to update the sharepoint objects then it will throw an exception **System.Exception: Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException** bcoz your code will be exploitable via a cross-site scripting. To prevent this CSS you have to set **AllowUnsafeUpdates** to true and after changes make it to false or whatever the previous value.

Also If the HTTPContext.Current is null then **AllowSafeUpdates** will be always true. This is the case in rich clients where no cross-scripting is possible as there are simply no web requests.