# AllowUnsafeUpdate on POST request

Tags: security, unsafe-updates

I am getting good old "The security validation for this page is invalid" on Sharepoint 2013, while updating list in Sharepoint, due to button click on an application page.

In browser, I clearly see, that this is a POST request. While debugging, I clearly see `Context.Request.HttpMethod == "POST"`.

I've tried adding `FormDigest` tag and calling `ValidateFormDigest` -- did not help.

What helped was the following:

```
using (SPWeb web = CurrentSite.OpenWeb())
{
        web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
        // List update here 
        web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
}
```

On MSDN, it is stated, that `AllowUnsafeUpdates` works only for GET requests.

How is that happening, that it is required even for my POST request? Am I doing everything correct?

Comment: This answer here may help you.
[may helpful][1] 


  [1]: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/137383/when-why-i-need-to-use-web-allowunsafeupdates-true

Answer (score 2):

The point is: you open a new `SPWeb` object (i.e. you don't use the contextual `SPContext.Current.Web` managed automatically by SharePoint on each request).
Therefore, no `FormDigest` can help here: `FormDigest` ensures security on POST request for the **contextual `SPWeb` only**.

`AllowUnsafeUpdates` helps here because it deactivates the security checks (both for `GET` and for `POST` requests).
The documentation mentions `GET` requests only, since they always consider you use the contextual `SPWeb`: for contextual `SPWeb`, only `GET` requests may need `AllowUnsafeUpdates`, since POST are always OK thanks to the `FormDigest` control injected via the master page.

Comment: What does it mean -- "FormDigest control injected via the master page"? When using contextual SPWeb, do I still need to `ValidateFormDigest `?

Comment: When using the contextual `SPWeb`, you don't need `ValidateFormDigest`, because the `FormDigest` control (injected by default by default master pages) manages the security checks on the contextual `SPWeb` for `POST` requests (but `AllowUnsafeUpdates` is still needed for `GET` requests even on the contextual `SPWeb`).